# ¿Como obtener la informacion que se encuentra en CDATA?

Tags: php, javascript

estoy intentando obtener unos datos de una factura electrónica en formato XML, algunos de los valores que necesito no están en la misma ruta siempre por lo que me he visto obligado tratar de obtener la información que se encuentra dentro de CDATA, el problema con esto que cuando intento acceder allí, no me muestra nada, es decir, me manda un array vacío, he estado investigando y no he dado con una solución a este problema.
La información que necesito es el Nit tanto del proveedor como el de la empresa que están ubicados en la rutas siguientes:
Nit Proveedor: /Invoice/cac:AccountingSupplierParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyTaxScheme/cbc:CompanyID
Nit Empresa: /Invoice/cac:AccountingCustomerParty/cac:Party/cac:PartyIdentification/cbc:ID

Anexo la parte del Codigo que he implementado para obtener la informacion, y la parte del archivo XML que estoy utilizando, no muestro todo el documento porque no me deja hacerlo.
Gracias por la ayuda.

```
$xmlRuta = '../archivos_facturacion/FACTURA_TMP/'.$_FILES['txtFacturaXML']['name'];
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlRuta,'SimpleXMLElement', LIBXML_NOCDATA);
            $ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
            $xml->registerXPathNamespace('cbc',$ns['cbc']);
            $xml->registerXPathNamespace('cac',$ns['cac']);
            //$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ccts',$ns['ccts']);
            $txtNumeroFactura = $xml->xpath('//cbc:ParentDocumentID')[0];
            $txtNitProveedor = $xml->xpath('//cac:SenderParty//cac:PartyTaxScheme//cbc:CompanyID')[0];
            $txtNombreProveedor = $xml->xpath('//cac:SenderParty//cac:PartyTaxScheme//cbc:RegistrationName')[0];
            $txtNitSociedad = $xml->xpath('//cac:ReceiverParty//cac:PartyTaxScheme//cbc:CompanyID')[0];
            $txtNombreSociedad = $xml->xpath('//cac:ReceiverParty//cac:PartyTaxScheme//cbc:RegistrationName')[0];
            $txtFechaFacturacion = $xml->xpath('//cbc:IssueDate')[0];
```

Solo muestro esto porque es donde tengo que acceder.

```
<![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?><ApplicationResponse xmlns:cac="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2" xmlns:cbc="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonBasicComponents-2" xmlns:ext="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonExtensionComponents-2" xmlns:sts="dian:gov:co:facturaelectronica:Structures-2-1" xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" xmlns="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:ApplicationResponse-2">
                    <ext:UBLExtensions>
                        <ext:UBLExtension>
                        <ext:ExtensionContent>
                            <sts:DianExtensions>
                            <sts:InvoiceSource>
                                <cbc:IdentificationCode listAgencyID="6" listAgencyName="United Nations Economic Commission for Europe" listSchemeURI="urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:codelist:gc:CountryIdentificationCode-2.1">CO</cbc:IdentificationCode>
                            </sts:InvoiceSource>
                            <sts:SoftwareProvider>
                                <sts:ProviderID schemeID="4" schemeName="31" schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)">800197268</sts:ProviderID>
                                <sts:SoftwareID schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)">...</sts:SoftwareID>
                            </sts:SoftwareProvider>
                            <sts:SoftwareSecurityCode schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)">...</sts:SoftwareSecurityCode>
                            <sts:AuthorizationProvider>
                                <sts:AuthorizationProviderID schemeID="4" schemeName="31" schemeAgencyID="195" schemeAgencyName="CO, DIAN (Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales)">800197268</sts:AuthorizationProviderID>
                            </sts:AuthorizationProvider>
                            </sts:DianExtensions>
                        </ext:ExtensionContent>
                        </ext:UBLExtension>
                        <ext:UBLExtension>
                        <ext:ExtensionContent><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Signature-fd77a419-fc58-49b6-bc66-4656539fde4a"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" /><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256" /><ds:Reference Id="Reference-4bd1a48d-c553-4df8-bebe-348efee20d72" URI=""><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" /></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><ds:DigestValue>b3DCchB29Fy/svLdXFT31eVQ5cAR2Pd1sDgKwXdH2g4=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference Id="ReferenceKeyInfo" URI="#Signature-fd77a419-fc58-49b6-bc66-4656539fde4a-KeyInfo"><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><ds:DigestValue>3lLpCnsyXSuARKhuNhRjef8lQigsCDSrRd7z451nl2w=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference><ds:Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#xmldsig-Signature-fd77a419-fc58-49b6-bc66-4656539fde4a-signedprops"><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><ds:DigestValue>nmXZBLciAo0ehEMlI0lygeitq3LhjgJR40Jp0SQLwIw=</ds:DigestValue></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue Id="SignatureValue-fd77a419-fc58-49b6-bc66-4656539fde4a">VPEqnjd7gGQSt1iEIkqhLKd9Se7PRWwptJAEllAPlCzbJxMXRKLTr95H+kSuyQnp5G8ystDs7YBYPYOMJwJ+kzqdEcZcjjGiOYW45CrKfDceX+zF7KoYVyY1x2+edgSD1n7iVX6Mll1lEsVj+3UbtYQjl+cmVSC8XiJh8Lrf4DlZd97u8clBrOrqdxtGD8dWWk4XnbTzZwWAKDF1rlxSVJpHvbgoxFMPbtBKZWEjSaVkETzQgdD928AKcdGTkEUBkYpzP6v1uyBxN8Wq1sfKl/piQmoEphONpB14YwOBPf/9n9FyU7o+tspnIllwGNSfAHYaelvMbAb/mOjHTcdpFQ==</ds:SignatureValue><ds:KeyInfo Id="Signature-fd77a419-fc58-49b6-bc66-4656539fde4a-KeyInfo"><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIIIyTCCBrGgAwIBAgIIOfuj6p79dRYwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwggFgMTkwNwYDVQQNDDBHU0UgU3Vib3JkaW5hdGUgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGUgMDAxIENvbG9tYmlhIEhXLUtVU1UxFjAUBgNVBAMMDUdTRSBTVUIwMDFfQ08xEzARBgNVBAUTCjkwMDIwNDI3MjgxGDAWBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWCWNhQGdzZS5jbzE0MDIGA1UECgwrR0VTVElPTiBERSBTRUdVUklEQUQgRUxFQ1RST05JQ0EgUy5BLiAtIEdTRTEgMB4GA1UEDAwXU3Vib3JkaW5hdGUgQ2VydGlmaWNhdGUxOzA5BgNVBAsMMkludGVybmV0IENlcnRpZmljYXRpb24gQXV0aG9yaXR5IGh0dHA6Ly93d3cuZ3NlLmNvMSIwIAYDVQQJDBlodHRwOi8vd3d3LmdzZS5jby9hZGRyZXNzMRYwFAYDVQQHDA1CT0dPVMOBLCBELkMuMQswCQYDVQQGEwJDTzAeFw0xODEyMTcyMDA0MDhaFw0yMDEyMTYyMDE0MDhaMIIBTjELMAkGA1UEBhMCQ08xIzAhBgkqhkiG9w0BCQEWFGpjb3J0ZXNhQGRpYW4uZ292LmNvMRQwEgYDVQQHDAtCT0dPVEEgRC5DLjEUMBIGA1UECAwLQk9HT1RBIEQuQy4xEzARBgNVBAUTCjgwMDE5NzI2ODQxOzA5BgNVBAMMMlUuQS5FLiBESVJFQ0NJT04gREUgSU1QVUVTVE9TIFkgQURVQU5BUyBOQUNJT05BTEVTMRowGAYDVQQMDBFGSVJNQSBFTEVDVFJPTklDQTFFMEMGA1UEDQw8Q0VSVElGSUNBRE8gREUgRklSTUEgRUxFQ1RST05JQ0EgLSBFTUlUSURPIFBPUiBHU0UgU1VCMDAxX0NPMSEwHwYDVQQJDBhDUkEgOCBOTy4gNkMgLSAzOCBQSVNPIDUxFjAUBg0rBgEEAYHzIAICAQICDANOSVQwggEiMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQDzxJV4gSLsZtW6ogxHiMaW+HDgrYYDkZ5zTM9HW24zD0Ked2lw1VAj3xah+Fj5nWwudCgR3EkfBlNB7rLF3Y1109EERIpzG7OwvszvvokblwNIovVoNzAIIOeSAlqpWsf0kw+GKGJtFnZVSLjcsZgdSaOkxD74Lrmz/seygcjGaIU39FJWaxFm7YceHR5V2cNtsqYIa9XbjQjf9rePIDz0WgmM1s8Tr/VsgX9pGgs/Xc1tlSUcQGzd78kjiBHEnbMYXJYO1I21WiqA5IeREpkQUZF7XJmmlnXws661Eu5zI2OowaoJLDYfBfE8KxwpnWnWMJAr3sFTIvxjuxHADT1nAgMBAAGjggKTMIICjzAMBgNVHRMBAf8EAjAAMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwID+DAzBgNVHSUELDAqBggrBgEFBQcDAQYIKwYBBQUHAwIGCCsGAQUFBwMEBgorBgEEAYI3CgMEMB0GA1UdDgQWBBTZ6JOIpLT1sZpiXrtWXYKfUoyZMTBtBggrBgEFBQcBAQRhMF8wHgYIKwYBBQUHMAGGEmh0dHA6Ly9vY3NwLmdzZS5jbzA9BggrBgEFBQcwAoYxaHR0cDovL2NlcnRzLmdzZS5jby9zdWIvY3J0X2dzZV9zdWIwMDFjb19zaGEyLmNydDAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBSOSgNeo/0Jp2O1ZO51Rnps3b5FSTB4BgNVHR8EcTBvMDWgM6Axhi9odHRwOi8vY3JsLmdzZS5jby9zdWIvY3JsX2dzZV9zdWIwMDFjb19zaGEyLmNybDA2oDSgMoYwaHR0cDovL2NybDEuZ3NlLmNvL3N1Yi9jcmxfZ3NlX3N1YjAwMWNvX3NoYTIuY3JsMBYGA1UdEgQPMA2BC2luZm9AZ3NlLmNvMIGzBgNVHSAEgaswgagwgaUGDSsGAQQBgfMgAgIDDgEwgZMwOQYIKwYBBQUHAgEWLWh0dHA6Ly9jcHMuZ3NlLmNvL3N1Yi9jcHNfc3ViMDAxY29fYWNfZ3NlLnBkZjBWBggrBgEFBQcCAjBKGkhUZXJtcyBvZiB1c2UgYXQgQ1BTIENBIEdTRSBodHRwOi8vY3BzLmdzZS5jby9zdWIvY3BzX3N1YjAwMWNvX2NhX2dzZS5wZGYwQwYIKwYBBQUHAQMENzA1MAgGBgQAjkYBATAIBgYEAI5GAQEwFQYGBACORgECMAsTA0VVUgIBAAIBADAIBgYEAI5GAQQwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQADggIBALr7wUEWUbtCWGpqlTlvaoQK2L/uwOsE1LJQx73Mj2oD0hP6wUEAVvZvo5llfGWYtAvBp4ZxmVRKfoxZtQ0TqU0ZHNfI9hsXqs+iAcURm4FpQd7Q/do+GVEMPJQh4VL1zxyjlAOgQLGDZM9rirBJmphKTnY6NOC4GIykiItD6MNRHVkr3WlIl+7LBJzKgsSk+W2tc+FtgMKEyZWLQ1kAUVuzkqiUNqkAzQDpQGdGa433s90Qo8/aPsA2Q5EWoqZSaKenoe9qFS7RkmaIX9dGOEJdgGGOkE0zkqn8IqqlFE60fM7tY3tae/kxoNX/XbS3YHVqxriFb2BkNGSt8AI7WCIJqpaFTXQG0WximZyQUYo2EhjajgY7v60oAGAz/bPI8vTZGBrN4qHTtVu7DnNrP5RIM/cM39u4cy7b3M8jwj6gBpdFlR28TMXLExA83ZGcdTxsdhOPfBS119zb56Uql7WIUE5GbwEghm1R6BVBjS54OPdK1TYfllqq6+g0X1iDLyugnLym3sHBVh3rwtuiMDf6x2tbXCbrW2MFuxibmKC/spJhtSIatCxgA0AWcEiv45R/7esHWFOZMI0xJX4XL0l2SiSaY5j20Pd2MxdZL8FlIxQqFLFNTWqVYRstcT1Qz7GO0rTyGolTDfLVf7KmYZtMpoXsk6C0iEwFheb9QjZl</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data><ds:KeyValue><ds:RSAKeyValue><ds:Modulus>88SVeIEi7GbVuqIMR4jGlvhw4K2GA5Gec0zPR1tuMw9CnndpcNVQI98WofhY+Z1sLnQoEdxJHwZTQe6yxd2NddPRBESKcxuzsL7M776JG5cDSKL1aDcwCCDnkgJaqVrH9JMPhihibRZ2VUi43LGYHUmjpMQ++C65s/7HsoHIxmiFN/RSVmsRZu2HHh0eVdnDbbKmCGvV240I3/a3jyA89FoJjNbPE6/1bIF/aRoLP13NbZUlHEBs3e/JI4gRxJ2zGFyWDtSNtVoqgOSHkRKZEFGRe1yZppZ18LOutRLucyNjqMGqCSw2HwXxPCscKZ1p1jCQK97BUyL8Y7sRwA09Zw==</ds:Modulus><ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent></ds:RSAKeyValue></ds:KeyValue></ds:KeyInfo><ds:Object Id="XadesObjectId-a2d6c7a4-bb8e-4d4a-a3f1-a0a281274852"><xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Id="QualifyingProperties-1f59fa70-6f7a-4dc7-b2c6-da3ca6b7aba6" Target="#Signature-fd77a419-fc58-49b6-bc66-4656539fde4a"><xades:SignedProperties Id="xmldsig-Signature-fd77a419-fc58-49b6-bc66-4656539fde4a-signedprops"><xades:SignedSignatureProperties><xades:SigningTime>2020-10-23T14:06:28-05:00</xades:SigningTime><xades:SigningCertificate><xades:Cert><xades:CertDigest><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><ds:DigestValue>9VF4DtAeT0c2iBjMCDb0B4yZdK55dqEUnuatF+D2dmI=</ds:DigestValue></xades:CertDigest><xades:IssuerSerial><ds:X509IssuerName>C=CO, L="BOGOTÁ, D.C.", STREET=http://www.gse.co/address, OU=Internet Certification Authority http://www.gse.co, T=Subordinate Certificate, O=GESTION DE SEGURIDAD ELECTRONICA S.A. - GSE, E=ca@gse.co, SERIALNUMBER=9002042728, CN=GSE SUB001_CO, Description=GSE Subordinate Certificate 001 Colombia HW-KUSU</ds:X509IssuerName><ds:X509SerialNumber>4178113307401352470</ds:X509SerialNumber></xades:IssuerSerial></xades:Cert></xades:SigningCertificate><xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier><xades:SignaturePolicyId><xades:SigPolicyId><xades:Identifier>https://facturaelectronica.dian.gov.co/politicadefirma/v2/politicadefirmav2.pdf</xades:Identifier><xades:Description /></xades:SigPolicyId><xades:SigPolicyHash><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256" /><ds:DigestValue>dMoMvtcG5aIzgYo0tIsSQeVJBDnUnfSOfBpxXrmor0Y=</ds:DigestValue></xades:SigPolicyHash></xades:SignaturePolicyId></xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier><xades:SignerRole><xades:ClaimedRoles><xades:ClaimedRole>supplier</xades:ClaimedRole></xades:ClaimedRoles></xades:SignerRole></xades:SignedSignatureProperties><xades:SignedDataObjectProperties><xades:DataObjectFormat ObjectReference="#Reference-4bd1a48d-c553-4df8-bebe-348efee20d72"><xades:MimeType>text/xml</xades:MimeType><xades:Encoding>UTF-8</xades:Encoding></xades:DataObjectFormat></xades:SignedDataObjectProperties></xades:SignedProperties></xades:QualifyingProperties></ds:Object></ds:Signature></ext:ExtensionContent>
                        </ext:UBLExtension>
                    </ext:UBLExtensions>
                    <cbc:UBLVersionID>UBL 2.1</cbc:UBLVersionID>
                    <cbc:CustomizationID>1</cbc:CustomizationID>
                    <cbc:ProfileID>DIAN 2.1</cbc:ProfileID>
                    <cbc:ProfileExecutionID>1</cbc:ProfileExecutionID>
                    <cbc:ID>77715824</cbc:ID>
                    <cbc:UUID schemeName="CUDE-SHA384">33e4f1e14f0e64c74a7f226d3cc1a7121fc8ca42ba32cc4e38755ee053f33944752303bee130a827e4679dfd45a71eab</cbc:UUID>
                    <cbc:IssueDate>2020-10-23</cbc:IssueDate>
                    <cbc:IssueTime>14:06:28-05:00</cbc:IssueTime>
                    <cac:SenderParty>
                        <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                        <cbc:RegistrationName>Unidad Especial Dirección de Impuestos y Aduanas Nacionales</cbc:RegistrationName>
                        <cbc:CompanyID schemeID="4" schemeName="1">800197268</cbc:CompanyID>
                        <cac:TaxScheme>
                            <cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID>
                            <cbc:Name>IVA</cbc:Name>
                        </cac:TaxScheme>
                        </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                    </cac:SenderParty>
                    <cac:ReceiverParty>
                        <cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                        <cbc:RegistrationName>PROVEEDOR SAS</cbc:RegistrationName>
                        <cbc:CompanyID schemeID="1" schemeName="31">23232232323</cbc:CompanyID>
                        <cac:TaxScheme>
                            <cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID>
                            <cbc:Name>IVA</cbc:Name>
                        </cac:TaxScheme>
                        </cac:PartyTaxScheme>
                    </cac:ReceiverParty>
                    <cac:DocumentResponse>
                        <cac:Response>
                        <cbc:ResponseCode>02</cbc:ResponseCode>
                        <cbc:Description>Documento validado por la DIAN</cbc:Description>
                        </cac:Response>
                        <cac:DocumentReference>
                        <cbc:ID>44018</cbc:ID>
                        <cbc:UUID schemeName="CUFE-SHA384">48ea2bb48db2505b9ad5e26a996c798cc2e3a2f6c2402f6cb9468d8e372f16bef95e945f962de866c5eaf87f536b44f8</cbc:UUID>
                        </cac:DocumentReference>
                        <cac:LineResponse>
                        <cac:LineReference>
                            <cbc:LineID>1</cbc:LineID>
                        </cac:LineReference>
                        <cac:Response>
                            <cbc:ResponseCode>0000</cbc:ResponseCode>
                            <cbc:Description>0</cbc:Description>
                        </cac:Response>
                        </cac:LineResponse>
                        <cac:LineResponse>
                        <cac:LineReference>
                            <cbc:LineID>2</cbc:LineID>
                        </cac:LineReference>
                        <cac:Response>
                            <cbc:ResponseCode>0</cbc:ResponseCode>
                            <cbc:Description>La Factura electrónica 44018, ha sido autorizada.</cbc:Description>
                        </cac:Response>
                        </cac:LineResponse>
                    </cac:DocumentResponse>
                    </ApplicationResponse>]]>
```

Answer (score 0):

Según [Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/CDATA)

> En un documento, una sección *CDATA* es aquella perteneciente a un documento que es marcado para que el analizador sintáctico lo interprete como **una cadena de caracteres y no como contenido etiquetado**.

La constante *LIBXML_NOCDATA* lo único que hace es obtener el contenido de *CDATA* como cadena, sin interpretarlo y no es realmente útil para acceder a tus datos.

Entonces, puedes intentar eliminar los caracteres correspondientes a la etiqueta antes de interpretar el contenido, cargando el archivo con [file_get_contents()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.file-put-contents.php), eliminando los caracteres correspondientes a *CDATA* con [str_replace()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.str-replace) y, finalmente, interpretando con [simplexml_load_string()](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.simplexml-load-string)

```
        $xmlRuta = '../archivos_facturacion/FACTURA_TMP/'.$_FILES['txtFacturaXML']['name'];
        // Cargar archivo y eliminar caracteres de CDATA
        $contenido = str_replace(['<![CDATA[', ']]>', file_get_contents($xmlRuta));
        // Inicializar XML desde cadena en lugar de archivo
        $xml = simplexml_load_string($contenido,'SimpleXMLElement');
        $ns = $xml->getNamespaces(true);
        $xml->registerXPathNamespace('cbc',$ns['cbc']);
        $xml->registerXPathNamespace('cac',$ns['cac']);
        //$xml->registerXPathNamespace('ccts',$ns['ccts']);
        $txtNumeroFactura = $xml->xpath('//cbc:ParentDocumentID')[0];
        $txtNitProveedor = $xml->xpath('//cac:SenderParty//cac:PartyTaxScheme//cbc:CompanyID')[0];
        $txtNombreProveedor = $xml->xpath('//cac:SenderParty//cac:PartyTaxScheme//cbc:RegistrationName')[0];
        $txtNitSociedad = $xml->xpath('//cac:ReceiverParty//cac:PartyTaxScheme//cbc:CompanyID')[0];
        $txtNombreSociedad = $xml->xpath('//cac:ReceiverParty//cac:PartyTaxScheme//cbc:RegistrationName')[0];
        $txtFechaFacturacion = $xml->xpath('//cbc:IssueDate')[0];
```

Cuando dices:

> Solo muestro esto porque es donde tengo que acceder.

Es probable que con esta "solución" obtengas algún error, tal vez por tener un documento *XML* dentro de otro y se deba buscar una alternativa, como modificar lo que se va a buscar para remplazar:

```
$contenido = str_replace([
        '<![CDATA[<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>', // Apertura de CDATA y documento XML
        ']]' // Cierre simple de CDATA
    ], '', file_get_contents($xmlRuta));
```